# $L$ is tangent to a curve $F$ at a point $P$ if and only if $I (P,F \cap L)>m_P(F)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

A line $L$ is tangent to a curve $F$ at a point $P$ if and only if $I (P,F \cap L)>m_P(F)$

I found this problem in Fulton, can one please tell how to do it ? I know that $I(P,F\cap L) \geq m_P(F)m_P(L)$ but since $L$ is a line and $P\in L$ we must have $m_P(L)=1$ and which means $I(P,F\cap L)\geq m_P(F)$. Now how to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full property reads

> $I(P,F \cap G) \geq m_p(F)m_p(G)$, with equality occurring if and only if $F$ and $G$ have no tangent lines in common at $P$.

What is the tangent line to $L$ at $P$?

Comment: Okay now I got it